# Will the php code run if I added a location.href script condition on the top of the code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, content-management-system

For example I have this following code:

```
<script>
     if(!document.referrer) { location.href = "/home"; }
</script>

<?php
     update_user_meta($user_id, "first_name", true);
?>
```

Will the php in the bottom will not run? Because I'm redirecting the page on the upper part? If so, what is the accuracy of my code? Is it 100% that is not going to run?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: php has run, shut up shop and gone home, before anything hits the browser. and its the browser that runs the JS.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you load a website(said it's php based)

php will compile .php first

so your `update_user_meta` will run

then when the php finished compile the file and send the content to browser

the js will then triggered by browser and return `/home`

hope this help :D